# Взлом замка. Проблема с циклом while

Tags: java, while

я наткнулся на следующую проблему: я пишу код по взлому замка, состоящего из 6 цифр (массив), и высчитываю время взлома. Эти цифры я заполняю рандомно в цикле, потом создаю новый массив, который так же заполняю рандомно и в цикле while сравниваю элементы (функция crackThePassword):

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
    static final int[] code = new int[6];
    static int[] myCode = new int[6];
    public static void password() {
        System.out.print("Изначальный код: ");
        for (int i : code) {
            code[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            System.out.print(code[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void crackThePassword() {
        System.out.print("Подобранный код: ");
        for(int i : myCode) {
            myCode[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            while(myCode[i] != code[i]) {
                myCode[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            System.out.print(myCode[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        password();
        System.out.println(" ");
        double startTime = System.nanoTime();
        crackThePassword();
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Время выполнения: " + duration + " сек");
    }
}
```

Но после цикла while у меня выводятся 6 подряд одинаковых цифр, пример:
Изначальный код: 810932
Подобранный код: 222222
Время выполнения: 0.1838 сек
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема кроется в коде функции `password`:

```java
public static void password() {
    System.out.print("Изначальный код: ");
    for (int i : code) {
        code[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(code[i]);
    }
}
```

Форма цикла `for (int i: code)` подставляет в `i` не индексы, а значения очередного элемента `code`. Поскольку массив `code` изначально не инициализирован, то считается, что все элементы равны нулю => заполняется только первый элемент, а остальные так и остаются нулями.

Аналогично дело и с `crackPassword`: там тоже берутся нули из пустого массива `myCode` и соответственно программа сравнивает только первый элемент массива.

Лучше всего не изобретать велосипед и использовать традиционное `for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++)`:

```java
package com.company;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
    static final int[] code = new int[6];
    static int[] myCode = new int[6];
    public static void password() {
        System.out.print("first: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
            code[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            System.out.print(code[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void crackThePassword() {
        System.out.print("second: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < myCode.length; i++) {
            myCode[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            while(myCode[i] != code[i]) {
                myCode[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            System.out.print(myCode[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        password();
        System.out.println(" ");
        double startTime = System.nanoTime();
        crackThePassword();
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();
        double duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000000;
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("time: " + duration + " s.");
    }
}

/*
first: 586507 
second: 586507 
time: 0.142075 s. // о повезло повезло
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду знать

Comment: @explazy пожалуйста. Рекомендую в дальнейших случаях, когда вопрос исчерпан, пометить ответ, наиболее близкий к верному (или тот, который больше всех помог в решении), верным (через галочку слева).